# Why are the JPG's greatly compressed on my Heroku deployed site?

Tags: node.js, heroku, gruntjs

When I deploy my site to Heroku, the JPG's are greatly compressed. For example, a JPG which should display as about 72k is showing up as 14k.

I am utilizing the imagemin grunt plugin to compress the image on deploy, however it compresses the image only slightly (original is about 84kb and it compresses to the aforementioned 72k) and the quality difference is not noticable. The correctly compressed image is making it onto the deployed instance. I've checked this by shelling into the deployed instance (via `heroku run bash`) and examining the file size (via `ls -l`) -- it does show up as being 72k.

I'm thinking this may be cache related because if I open the image in a new tab (I'm using chrome) and `ctrl f5` to reload it uncached, it does come as the expected 72k. Unfortunately, doing a similar type of refresh on the main site doesn't seem to be bring the correctly compressed images.

It's also a bit perplexing that I've never to my knowledge compressed the images so greatly. The grunt imagemin plugin only has one option (progressive) and while I have in the past played around with toggling that option, it only affects the image size by a small degree. So, if this is caching related, I have no idea where the super compressed ones came from in the first place.

Can anybody shed some light as to what is happening?

Comment: Could you add your gruntfile? Did you add the optimizationLevel parameter to imagemin task?

Comment: @MarioAraque The gruntfile is [here](https://github.com/rmisio/robmisio/blob/master/Gruntfile.js). I'm not using optimizationLevel, but it looks like that's for PNGs, not JPGs. Also, the main problem is that when viewing the deployed site, the browser seems to be showing an uber compressed image. If I build locally, this is not the case. Nor is it the case if I view the actual file on the cloud that should be being served. I can't figure out where the super compressed image is coming from.